# Python speed up permutation of bits within 32Bit number

Tags: python, performance, set, permutation

I'm interested in reordering the bits within a number, and since I want to do it several trillion times, I want to do it fast.

Here are the details: given a number `num` and an order matrix `order`.
`order` contains up to ~6000 lines of permutations of the numbers 0..31.
These are the positions to which the bits change.

Simplified example: `binary(num) = 1001`, `order[1]=[0,1,3,2]`, reordered number for `order[1]` would be `1010` (binary).

Now I want to know, if my input number `num` is the smallest of these (~6000) reordered numbers. I'm searching for all 32-Bit numbers which fullfill this criterion.
My current approach is to slow, so I'm looking for a speedup.

minimal-reproducible-example:

```
num = 1753251840
order = [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
[ 3,  2,  1,  0,  7,  6,  5,  4, 11, 10,  9,  8, 15, 14, 13, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 23, 22, 21, 20, 27, 26, 25, 24, 31, 30, 29, 28],
[15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16],
[31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8, 7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
[21, 20, 23, 22, 29, 28, 31, 30, 17, 16, 19, 18, 25, 24, 27, 26,  5,  4,  7,  6, 13, 12, 15, 14, 1,  0,  3,  2,  9,  8, 11, 10]]
  
patterns=set()
bits = format(num, '032b')
for perm in order:
    bitsn = [bits[perm[i]] for i in range(32)]
    patterns.add(int(''.join(bitsn),2))
print( min(patterns)==num)
```

Where can I start to improve this?

Comment: If you are looking to do *anything* "several trillion times", then your first action should be to use a compiled language. No matter how good an algorithm is, paying the price for dynamic dispatch several trillion times will wreck performance.

Comment: [Check this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to iterate over permutations one by one rather than generating it. But as @MisterMiyagi mentioned, `several trillion times` won't be fast in Python.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not interested in all permutations, just special ones, which I calculated by using itertools ;)

Comment: Is it expected that the `min(patterns)` give `65814` and not num (resulting in a wrong condition)?

Comment: as said above, compiled language would be a better choice here. If you insist on Python, then it could be worth trying to use [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) if its JIT compiler wouldnt be helpful here. Eventually [Cython](https://cython.org/) could also help.

Comment: Note that in order for this to be answerable, you should precisely define *what* improvement you are looking for. Just "how would you improve this?" is very broad and seems more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though. If you are looking for performance improvements, please clearly define what you consider sufficient – likely not a few ms here or there, but some (how many?) orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting bits **using string is generally very inefficient** (whatever the language). The same thing also apply for parsing. Moreover, for such a fast low-level operation, you need to use a **JIT or a compiled language** as comments already pointed out.

Here is a prototype using the Numba's JIT (assume all numbers are unsigned):

```py
npOrder = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
    [ 3,  2,  1,  0,  7,  6,  5,  4, 11, 10,  9,  8, 15, 14, 13, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 23, 22, 21, 20, 27, 26, 25, 24, 31, 30, 29, 28],
    [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16],
    [31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8, 7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
    [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
    [21, 20, 23, 22, 29, 28, 31, 30, 17, 16, 19, 18, 25, 24, 27, 26,  5,  4,  7,  6, 13, 12, 15, 14, 1,  0,  3,  2,  9,  8, 11, 10]], dtype=np.uint32)

@njit
def extractBits(num):
    bits = np.empty(32, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(32):
        bits[i] = (num >> i) & 0x01
    return bits

@njit
def permuteAndMerge(bits, perm):
    bitsnFinal = 0
    for i in range(32):
        bitsnFinal |= bits[31-perm[i]] << i
    return bitsnFinal

@njit
def computeOptimized(num):
    bits = extractBits(num)
    permCount = npOrder.shape[0]
    patterns = np.empty(permCount, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in range(permCount):
        patterns[i] = permuteAndMerge(bits, npOrder[i])
    # The array can be converted to a set if needed here with: set(patterns)
    return min(patterns) == num
```

This code is about 25 time faster than the original one on my machine (ran 5 000 000 times).
You can also use Numba to accelerate and parallelize the loop that run the function `computeOptimized` resulting in a significant additional speed-up.

Note that this code can be again much faster in C or C++ using low-level processor instructions ([available for example on many x86_64 processors](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb)). With that and parallelism, the order of magnitude of the execution speed should be close to a billion of permutation per second.

Comment: thx. I have to look up the new input from this answer before responding.

Comment: nice. I have a speedup of about a factor 20 too. Thanks for pointing out those features, I will read more into it since I'm not familiar with python libraries/functionalities. Including C would be my last resort but I guess this improvement is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of possible speed-ups, staying with Python and the current algorithm:

- Bail out as soon as you find a pattern less than `num`; once one like that is found, the condition cannot possibly be true. (You also don't need to store `patterns`; at most a flag whether an equal one was found, if that's not guaranteed by the problem.)
- `bitsn` could be a generator expression, and doesn't need to be in a variable; you'll have to measure whether that's faster.

More fundamental improvements:

- If you want to find all the numbers (rather than just test a particular one), it feels like there ought to be a faster algorithm by considering what the bits mean. A couple of hours thinking could potentially let you process just the 6000 lists, rather than all 2³² integers.
- As others have written, if you're after pure speed, python is not the ideal language. That depends on the balance of how much time you want to spend on programming vs on running the program.

Side note:

- Are the 32-bit integers signed or unsigned?

Comment: thx. I  will look up generator expressions. I'm looking for unsigned integers.

Comment: Ah, generator expression just means omitting the `[]` from the `[... for ... in ...]` expression, like this: `''.join(bits[perm[i]] for i in range(32))`. The main restriction is that you can only use the result of a generator expression once, while a list can be used multiple times.